# How to prepare a KFC - like coating for fried chicken?

Tags: chicken, frying

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make extra crispy and crunchy breading like KFC?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/5764/how-to-make-extra-crispy-and-crunchy-breading-like-kfc)

Hi all.

What is your experience on this? I know that probably it is not possible to achieve the same flavour as for the oryginal recipe but I would like read your recipes.

I can not come even close to this on myself...