# How to make ridge structure of crispy chicken

Tags: substitutions, chicken, texture, batter

In food shop, we see many fold ridges on crispy chicken like this Picture:
[image]

While googling about the secret, I found most of them advised to put the chicken pieces in a bag after dipping it in the butter, then shake, dip and re shake. But in practical, this shaking process does not create ridges structure [Like in the above picture]. In many youtube videos, although at the beginning of the video, it is showing ridges picture, but after completion of the video, the chicken pieces do not cover with ridges. Some other advised to use corn flakes to make these ridge structure. But corn flakes are expensive.

My question is how to make these ridges without corn flakes? Is there any alternative or real video tutorial?

Comment: This question and answers may help you out - https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/5764/35357

Comment: In this picture, you can see the curled shape of cornflakes.

Comment: I believe this kind of coating is often the result of batter-coating the chicken, not dredging them in any kind of flour/cereal.  Perhaps search for recipes that involve batters, as opposed to dredging in in different things?

Answer (score 6):

In many places cornflakes are very cheap, I am assuming where you are they are expensive because they are imported. You aren't going to be able to get the ridged structure without something like cornflakes because it's the flakes themselves that give the breading that texture. You need to find something that you can afford, perhaps another cereal that is similar to cornflakes would work, it all depends on what you have in the stores. If you can find them Panko breadcrumbs would give you a nice texture, not the same as cornflakes but pretty good. Otherwise I suggest you go shopping and see what you can find.

Comment: would potato crisps or chips work? Those should be common and relatively cheap in most places

Comment: I tried potato chips, but it did not work. Chips absorbs water and become soft. So it would not create ridge structure.

Comment: are you frying or baking your chicken pieces? deep frying?

Comment: Japanese Karaage batter and tempura batter can create ridge effects without adding another solid crunchy bits like cornflakes. Possibilities?

Answer (score 6):

It's not that difficult to make flakes out of starch, if taste is not your major concern, as you are going to season and fry them and not eat with milk.

All you need is flour of your choice and water.

1. Take a skillet and fill it evenly with flour, the thickness of cornflakes.
2. Sprinkle water over the flour, till the flour is just soaked with water. Do not create a dough, just let the water soak in.
3. Heat the pan so the water starts to evaporate.
4. Now carefully scramble the mixture like when you do scrambled eggs.

Answer (score 5):

The way I achieve this texture is to place the chicken in a large bowl and pour evaporated milk over it - just enough to wet all of the pieces well. I mix the pieces around with my hands to make sure the chicken is coated well with the milk. Then I pour a generous amount of seasoned self-rising flour over the chicken and mix it around with my hands to ensure that all of the chicken is coated well. (You should end up with a thick, semi-moist coating on the chicken.)

At this point, if you want, you can add a little more evaporated milk and mix the chicken around in the flour again. (I don't usually do this as the first steps give me the texture I want, much like what you see in your picture.)

Before frying I remove the chicken from the bowl, lay the chicken pieces on a piece of foil or a dish, and let the coating set for ~15 minutes. (Longer time won't hurt.)

If you use any seasoning(s), be sure to season your chicken beforehand. I use the same seasoning(s) in the flour as I use on the chicken.