# Potato Starch Coating water to starch ratio?

Tags: food-science, chinese-cuisine, cornstarch

I made some General Tso's Chicken last night using a batter of potato starch and water then frying in peanut oil. I used just enough water to wet the starch and make it somewhat pliable but if I let it sit for a minute it was so thick but if I gave it a bit of stir I could coat the chicken.

My question is, what is a good water to potato or corn starch ratio to be able to coat the chicken easily and give it that amazingly crisp coating even after tossing with the sauce? The type of coating I'm after is light and crispy, not doughy.

Comment: "Best" is difficult standard to judge objectively. It largely depends on what you are aiming for, tempura batter or something more 'KFC'. What other ingredients (if any) are you using? Whatever anyone here may say you are going to have to exercise a little 'trial and error' to get to what you think is 'best' for you...

Comment: I've updated the question to better clarify @CosCallis

Comment: Very related, but I don't know enough chicken frying to say if it is a duplicate: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/5764/how-to-make-extra-crispy-and-crunchy-breading-like-kfc

Comment: @rumtscho - I'm sorry but there isn't any egg or flour in this recipe and that question relates to southern US style chicken, not Chinese fried chicken which uses either potato or corn starch. Thanks!