# How do I achieve a crust like this fried chicken?

Tags: chicken

I normally use a mixture of flour and cornstarch, dredging the chicken twice (in buttermilk, then flour, then buttermilk, then flour again) but I have not been able to achieve a crust like the chicken below

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make extra crispy and crunchy breading like KFC?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/5764/how-to-make-extra-crispy-and-crunchy-breading-like-kfc)

Comment: I would bet that that isn't a dredged coating but a very thin batter.  Good tempura often has that same kind of texture.

Answer (score 3):

I do not know about the chicken in the photo, it appears certainly crunchy, but not very appealing to me... 
anyway, the first dredging you do in buttermilk is useless: normally you have three phases for perfectly breading food for frying:

1. dredging in flour (wheat flour, starch or anything else, even a mixture of flour and powdered spices that also make the meat tastier) is important because it "dries" the chicken surface and consent a better coating of the liquid;
2. dip in a sticky liquid to coat:  the support for the crunchy finish. can be buttermilk, beaten eggs, milk... the denser the liquid the thicker the coating
3. the "breading", that can be made of flour, breadcrumbs, sesame seeds, natural rolled oat, crushed cornflakes...

For juicier meat is better to marinate or brine it the night before
for crispiness the frying temperature must be controlled and well kept at around 165°C

Comment: Yeah, this appears to be cornflakes, but they didn’t crush them up enough for my taste. You can also introduce some of your wet coating into your breading to encourage clumping.

Comment: Plus 1 for the not very appealing :)